# Get rows with same field in ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: group-by, arcobjects

ArcGIS 10.1 using ArcObjects in .NET. Im well adept at iterating through all the features in a featureclass. However I've spent the better half of a day trying to look for a way to group features by a field.

I currently use:

```
Dim pFeatCursor As IFeatureCursor = pPolylineFeatLayer.Search(Nothing, False)
Dim pPolylineFeature As IFeature = pFeatCursor.NextFeature
While Not pPolylineFeature Is Nothing
   'do something with the single feature

   pPolylineFeature = pFeatCursor.NextFeature
End While
```

What Im trying to do is:

```
'group features by fields "CODE3" and "AIDX"

for every group
   'dump that group of features to it's own featureclass
next group
```

I've been looking at several cursor classes and cant seem to find any that do this type of query. this python function seems to do the trick but need to do this in .NET and this tool is only available in ModelBuilder.

```
arcpy.IterateFeatureSelection_mb( Input_Features, Group_By_Fields, "false")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use IQueryFilterDefinition.PostfixClause with a 'GROUP BY' or 'ORDER BY'

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work on shapefiles, only geodbs. Thanks for the tip though.